# How to download a formatted Excel into a selected directory

Tags: r, excel, download, shiny

I would like my Shiny app to apply conditional formatting to the result and let my users save the formatted table to a folder of their choosing.

Here is my code. I got this message when I ran it.

```
Warning: Error in as.data.frame.default: cannot coerce class "structure("Workbook", package = "openxlsx")" to a data.frame
```

**app.R:**

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
  column(DT::dataTableOutput('sw'), width = 6),
  br(),

  downloadButton('download', "Save")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #Dummy data. Actual data is reactive.
  result <- reactive({
    a <- c (NA, 120, 91, 74)
    b <- c(120, NA, 109, 119)
    c <- c(91, 109, NA, 121)
    d <- c(74, 119, 121, NA)

    return(data.frame(a, b, c,d))
  })

  output$sw <- DT::renderDataTable({
      brks    <- quantile(result(), probs = seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm = TRUE)
      colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("indianred1","white","mediumseagreen"))
      clrs    <- colfunc(length(brks) + 1)
      DT::datatable(result(), rownames = TRUE, options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE))  %>% formatStyle(colnames(result()), backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))
  })

  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {paste("Result.xlsx")},
    content  = function(file) {

      wb <- createWorkbook()
      negStyle <- createStyle(bgFill = "#FFC7CE")
      posStyle <- createStyle(bgFill = "#C6EFCE")

      addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1")
      writeData(wb = wb, sheet="Sheet1", x = result(), startRow = 1, startCol = 1)

      posStyle <- createStyle(bgFill = "#C6EFCE")
      conditionalFormatting(wb, "Sheet1", cols=3:ncol(result()), rows=2:(1+nrow(result())), rule="<=80", style = negStyle)
      conditionalFormatting(wb, "Sheet1", cols=3:ncol(result()), rows=2:(1+nrow(result())), rule=">120", style = posStyle)

      write.xlsx(x = wb, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

UPDATE: 2/6/2018

Changing the following

```
write.xlsx(x = wb, file)
```

to

```
saveWorkbook(wb, file)
```

works perfectly.

Comment: What other packages are you using? Presumably `openxlsx` but where is the `formatStyle()` fx coming from?

I think you're getting this error because you're trying to write a workbook `wb` using `write.xlsx()` which is similar to `write.csv()` or any other `write.[x]()` fx. For workbooks, you should be using `saveWorkbook()` but I don't know how `saveWorkbook()` will react in a `Shiny` app.

Comment: Steven formatStyle() fx is part of the DT package. Hence DT::datatable. In my example, formatStyle() is only used to format the rendered output$sw (which is shown on the browser). If you have any other ideas, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This small script works fine on my Windows 7 system.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(XLConnect)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "excel download"),
  dashboardSidebar(downloadLink("downloadData", "Download")),
  dashboardBody(),
  skin = "purple"
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data1 <- mtcars
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){"mtcars.xlsx"},
    content = function(file) {
      fname <- paste(file,"xlsx",sep=".")
      wb <- loadWorkbook(fname,create = TRUE)
      createSheet(wb,"cars")
      writeWorksheet(wb,data = data1,sheet = "cars")
      saveWorkbook(wb)
      file.rename(fname,file)
    },
    contentType="application/xlsx" 
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```